# Information to be kept for non-repudiation?

Tags: x509certificate, digital-signature

I'm using Java applet to sign XML files in a web browser. 
what information, in addition to X509 key which is included in signed XML, should I keep to ensure non-repudiation?
I have seen applets transferring private key (encrypted using same private key) or just public key.

Answer (score 0):

In `XMLDsig`/`XAdES` signature, the non-repudiation (proof of the integrity and origin of data) is provided by the signature itself.

The integrity is provided because if you change any bytes of the signature you will broke it (the signature can't validate), and the origin of data is provided by the [`<xmldsig:keyInfo>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-KeyInfo) element which provides you the necessary certificate to validate the signature (however this element it's optional, so if it's not present it's supposed that application context it's enough to get that certificate), if the signature validate with this certificate you've the identity of the signature author. Besides in XAdES standard is defined the [`<xades:SigningCertificate>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XAdES/#Syntax_for_XAdES_The_SigningCertificate_element) attribute which is mandatory and also it references the necessary certificate to validate the signature.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

You should *never* transfer a private key except possibly for backup. The safest method of keeping a private key safe is to create a key pair at the location where the private key is required and then transfer the public key using a certificate request.

To verify and validate a certificate, and therefore a signature, you need the following things:

1. A chain of certificates that starts with the certificate of the key pair used for the signature, up to some trusted certificate. The chain can exist of 1 self signed certificate, but usually it's longer. Usually you trust some root certificate, have 1 or 2 CA certificates, ending with the leaf certificate that performs the signing.
2. Some method of verifying that any of the certificates in the chain was not revoked. Usually this is a frequently distributed CRL or OCSP.
3. A clock. Without a trusted clock it is not possibly to verify if the certificate has expire.

These are all required for verification. For signing, you don't have to keep anything. Of course, you normally hold on to your private key and certificate.